# mysql_fetch_assoc fetching only one record

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array with the result of a query:

```
.....some code.....
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vttest");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

But it only prints one record, I can't put $row in a loop because I will be working on sorting that variable later.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [rep] => Mike
    [name] => Joe
    [department] => Business
    [location] => Room 1
    [email] => xxxx@hotmail.com
    [phone] => 519-123-4567
    [type] => Visit
    [drink] => Coffee
    [notes] => Some notes
    [lastVisited] => 2010-08-27
    [nextVisit] => 2010-08-27
)
```

I know there are more records than that, how can I print all of it while still being able to work with the $row variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "working on sorting that variable later" and "work with the $row variable?"  It's quite possible that you could handle the sorting at the query level and not have to worry about it in your PHP code...  There are a variety of techniques available, but I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: That was actually another topic why I had to do the sorting after the query, basically I had to be able to resort the $data variable, that's why if I keep fetching the array I don't think I will be able to sort it, so I need to find a way to display everything in that $row variable without having to resort to any kind of fetch loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are actually getting one record because you need to use a loop to get all records.:

```
$my_arary = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $my_arary[] = $row;
  print_r($row);
}
```

As you said, later you can use the `$my_arary` to do whatever you like.

Comment: This works though I had to replace `mysql_fetch_assoc` with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` (included the "i" after mysql...) using PHP 7.2.7

Comment: this is not giving me the first record, rest all is coming

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it in a loop. And then, if you need to work on that variable later, use [`mysql_data_Seek`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) to reset internal result pointer:

```
 mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
 // your later code.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vttest");

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($data, $row);
}
```

Comment: this makes it create new rows

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, you needed to use a loop to go though the results to get each row, and as you do so assign each row to a table.

The following with be something your be looking for.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vttest");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Then all you need to do to access that array is the following.

```
foreach($rows as $index => $value){
    print_r($value);
}
```

The foreach will print each row with in your array one at a time, letting you short or use that data as you wish.