# Mysql Fetch Array ASSOC return single row with no assoc

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
function getContact(){
  try{
    $db = new DBConnection();
    $db->getConnection();
    $sql = "select * from `contact`";
    $handle = mysql_query($sql);
    $rowRes = mysql_fetch_array($handle, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    }catch(Exception $e){
  }
  return $rowRes;
}
```

When I run

```
$contactArr =  getContact();
print_r($contactArr);
```

The result return was

1leadsBun Lowbun@12345.com82883810

And I got 2 records in my database and print_r only show one.

print_r also does not print in array structure.

What should i do to make its work as an array when i print_r($rowRes) and it should returns its assoc and its 2 rows.

**THANKS FOR HELPING!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_assoc fetching only one record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587300/mysql-fetch-assoc-fetching-only-one-record)

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop like

```
while($rowRes = mysql_fetch_array($handle, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($rowRes);
}
```

EDIT:

`mysql_fetch_array()` Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead. In this case we have 2 rows. First it returns first row and moves the pointer ahead. But not fetches the row. To fetch the second row we have to loop again. After second row there are no more rows so it returns FALSE and while loop quits.

Please read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Hi Kiren, thanks for your effort. Can you elaborate more about the basic fonction of 'looping', per example, explain the OP what an array is, and why it's result is not has expected. Improving your answer will avoid flagging because of its length. Also, indenting your coding will present a more 'professionnal' point of view/answer and kill other users the urge to indent it for you.

Comment: Thanks Kiren, that looks better ;) Tell me, did that 'flagging' prompted you to reconsider your answer?

Comment: No it is not the matter of downvote or upvote. You just asked another question I answered it thats it :)

Comment: oups, i am sorry, by 'flagging' i did not meant voting up or down your answer. I just invited you to elaborate a little more about it because it WAS flagged for deletion and then wanted to know if i/it was helping you.

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes it helped me. 'Flagged for deletion' means what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68321/discussion-between-milche-patern-and-kiren-siva).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add while loop code is below

```
$data = array();
while($rowRes = mysql_fetch_array($handle, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $rowRes;
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with mysql_fetch_row() function under loop like.

```
while($rowRes = mysql_fetch_row($handle) {
   print_r($rowRes);
}
```

This will return the records in array like you want.